# Linking to the object

Tags: python, object

I am new in python and I have one problem :/ In the function get longest name I want to return the name of the person but instead of it I am keeping returning just link? of this person. Could you help me and say where it is a problem? Thank you :)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, degree):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
        self.degree = degree
        self.mentor = None
        self.mentees = []


def create_mentorship(mentor, mentee):
    mentee.mentor = mentor
    mentor.mentees.append(mentee)


def get_longest_name(people):
    return (max(people, key=lambda word: (len(word), word)))


people = {}
people['martin'] = Person('Martin', 1991, 'phd')
people['peter'] = Person('Peter', 1995, 'bc')
get_longest_name(people)
```

I am getting.... ->    'martin'

I should get.... ->    'Martin'

Comment: You're iterating over a dictionary - which will yield it's keys. You could return `people[max(...)]` or pass `people.items()` into the sort function (which you'll need to tweak)

Comment: Why do you believe you should get `'martin'`? `people` is a `dict` object containing various `Person` objects. You never access the `.name` attribute on these `Person` objects, rather, you simply iterate over the keys of your `dict`, which seem to be lower-case versions of the `.name` attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get_longest_name function is returning the key in the dictionary, rather than the attributes of the class.  The following would fix it:

```
def get_longest_name(people):
    return people[max(people, key=lambda word: (len(word), word))].name
```

Edit to add a full working answer:

```
>>> class Person:
...     def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, degree):
...         self.name = name
...         self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
...         self.degree = degree
...         self.mentor = None
...         self.mentees = []
...
>>> def get_longest_name(people):
...     return people[max(people, key=lambda word: (len(word), word))].name
...
>>> people = {}
>>> people['martin'] = Person('Martin', 1991, 'phd')
>>> people['peter'] = Person('Peter', 1995, 'bc')
>>> get_longest_name(people)
Martin
```

Comment: Thank U :) I really appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the keys, not the values. Try this:

```
return people[max(people, key=lambda word: (len(word), word))].name
```

Access the object in the `people` dictionary and return its name.

As well, you could access the names of each `Person` object in the dictionary:

```
return max(people.values(), key=lambda person: (len(person.name), person.name)).name
```